# Update Firefox developers edition

Tags: updates, firefox

When I open my Firefox developers edition on Ubuntu it always asks me for update , when I click I have a permission error .

How can I update it ?

Comment: Can you add the screenshot of the error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to run Firefox as root.

Firefox is trying to update its system files from your personal account.

It is a little wonky, but the stock version does not have this issue because it updates with the rest of the system.

1- Close all other Firefox windows.

2- Open a terminal in the folder that you installed firefox into (mine ended up in ~/Downloads/firefox).

OP had his installed at: `/opt/firefox_dev/firefox`

3- Run:
`sudo ./firefox-bin` in that terminal. The terminal must be "in" whatever folder you are running Firefox Dev edition in.

4- Help -> About -> Update

**I probably shouldn't need to mention this, but don't visit any websites in this mode, and close it as soon as it is done.**

Comment: I know that I have to run as a root but how ?

Comment: See edit; probably should have added that earlier.

Comment: Firefox normal edition opens not firefox developers edition

Comment: You'll need to find the name of the program, then I'm downloading it now. You got it from here? : https://www.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/developer/

Comment: Oh, Thanks it worked the folder firefox developer edition was under is `/opt/firefox_dev/firefox`, then I went to Help -> About -> Update !

Please update question than I will accept it .

Comment: I dont see Help --> About --> Update

Answer (score 1):

Change the ownership of firefox developer edition. Then it will update automatically.

run this comand:

```
sudo chown -R $USER /opt/firefox
```